# How Can I get autofocus on the first element (buildform) symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

In my TopicType class, I used :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('title', 'text')
            ->add('content', 'ckeditor', array(
                'label' => 'Contenu',
                'config_name' => 'my_custom_config',
                'config' => array('language' => 'fr'),))
            ->add('save', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

How can I get autofocus on my first field "title", when i display the form?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$builder->add('title', 'text', array(
    'attr' => array(
        'autofocus' => true
        )
    );
```

Comment: Hi @malcolm, it's work with google chrome, but not on firefox. `<input id="bissap_forumbundle_topic_title" name="bissap_forumbundle_topic[title]" required="required" autofocus="1" type="text">`

Comment: You can set `'autofocus' => 'autofocus'`

Comment: Now, I have `<input id="bissap_forumbundle_topic_title" name="bissap_forumbundle_topic[title]" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">` but it still does not work...

Comment: It's work for me on firefox, opera, chrome. You can try `'autofocus' => null` but output will be `autofocus=""` all of that should work on browsers, never had problems with this. If you need `autofocus`, you can do it in Twig template.

Comment: I don't know...For this form i used, a data-prototype with click event : `<a id="creatThread" data-prototype="{{ form(form)|e }}" class="btn btn-primary right-flt creatThread" href="#">Create topic</a>` I'm going to try with hidden element...

Comment: You should set autofocus with javascript then : `$("#bissap_forumbundle_topic_title").focus();`

Comment: This seems to work for me on FF and Chrome on Ubuntu. What is the support for this on IE and Safari?

Comment: On Symfony 6.2.7 this produces `autofocus="autofocus"`

Answer (score 2):

The realy crossbrowser way is to type

```
$builder->add('title', 'text', array(
'attr' => array(
    'autofocus' => null
    )
);
```

This code produces just `autofocus` attribute without `=` sign and any value.

Comment: On Symfony 6.2.7 this produces `autofocus=""`.