# merge key=>value into value in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

This is mostly for curiosity, but I would love to be able to do this.

Basically I have a situation where I would like to enter an `autofocus` into a form using Symfony's FormBuilder.  It is possible to enter this by using something like this

```
->add('textField', null,
            array('attr' => array('class' => 'text-field-ex', 'autofocus' => true)))
```

However, as a result, this ends up producing `autofocus="1"` in the resulting form.   This works fine for Chrome, but Firefox does not like this format;  it prefers `autofocus` to live alone, and not as an attribute;  hence it does not work.  This is easy to do in raw php code, but for some reason Symfony does not want to do this.

I know this has been (sort of) addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299045/how-can-i-get-autofocus-on-the-first-element-buildform-symfony), and as is suggested in the comments, this can be handled relatively easily with Javascript, this to me seems like an imperfect solution, due to inherent instabiity.  I have it working this way, but I'd rather have the code itself be rendered properly the first time.

I have tried something like this:

```
$autofocus = 'autofocus';
->add('textField', null,
            array('attr' => array('class' => 'text-field-ex', $autofocus)))
```

But this simply turns the resulting form field to be `"0"=autofocus` and still does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to handle this directly in Symfony?

Comment: have you tried autofocus="autofocus"

Comment: yes.  Same problem. .

Comment: Unless you're looking to modify the underlying Symphony code, this appears to be asked-and-answered, and you're just not happy with the answer.

Comment: @PatrickQ This is correct.  However as I mentioned;  I found the answers to be inadequate, as this sort of functionality should be possible.  It's extremely easy in raw php.  I might be interested in modifying the underlying code;  it seems like a feature that could be useful. If you have any suggestions along that path, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You could just override the `block_widget` in your templates (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) and replace the way it outputs attributes with something along those lines :

```
{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}
  {% if attrname == 'autofocus' %}
    autofocus
  {% else %}
    {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

It's cleaner than a javascript solution I guess.

Comment: that was a good approach, however sadly it did not work;  it returned `autofocus=""`.  I attempted to use `replace` however that only seems to work on either keys or values;  as far as I can tell, I can't find any way of changing the operator.

Comment: You're directly outputting HTML through Twig, so it works (and I just tried it, it works well) — so either your override is not taken into account, either you're doing something else in your code ...

Comment: I understand how twig works. Try it in Firefox.  It works fine in Chrome, but Firefox needs autofocus to stand on its own.